# How to run a stage only on merge request?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a stage that should only be completed when a merge is opened or updated.
It appears to be doing its job, but when it is accepted, a new pipeline is run again. Is there a simple solution for this?

gitlab in version 13

```
lint-backend:
  image: maven:3.8.1-openjdk-17-slim
  stage: lint-backend
  allow_failure: false
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
    changes:
      - "backend/**/*"    
  except:
    - develop
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"
  script:
    - echo "test"
```

Comment: I think your configuration looks correct to only run this job on merge requests. Though when you say **"but when it is accepted, a new pipeline is run again"** -- is the `lint-backend` job in that pipeline? Or is your question how to stop the pipeline that happens after merge altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline is behaving as expected, because `merge_requests` refers to any event happening around an MR. As such, marking an MR as approved triggers a new pipeline due to this new event happening.

I'd suggest migrating over to [`rules:if`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html) instead of using `only/except` (which is now deprecated) to control your pipeline execution, as you'll have more flexibility and can capture more specific scenarios as this one. Using your example, the CI file could look similar to this:

```yaml
lint-backend:
  image: maven:3.8.1-openjdk-17-slim
  stage: lint-backend
  allow_failure: false
  rules:
    # If I'm on develop, skip the pipeline
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      when: never
    # When in a MR but the MR is still unapproved, schedule the pipeline. Will not trigger when MR is approved
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED == "false"
      changes:
      - "backend/**/*"    
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"
  script:
    - echo "test"
```

There are more [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines) you can use to make your setup complex and cover more scenarios.

Also bear in mind that the ordering in `rules` is important as those are evaluated sequentially, so a good strategy is to put scenarios that would avoid triggering this pipeline at the top.

Comment: ty very much @bhito, but the variable CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED is the from version 14.1